# Find the shortest string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i find the shortest string in javascript array with different count of array elements? 
I used

```
var min = Math.min(arr[0].length,arr[1].length,arr[2].length);
```

and i have result like shortest string between 3 elements of array. But I don't want to care about numbers of elements

Comment: you could sort by length.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of lengths, and then apply it to [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min):

```js
var arr = ['cats', 'giants', 'daughters', 'ice'];
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, arr.map(function(str) { return str.length; }));
console.log(min);
```

Or use ES6's [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and arrow function:

```js
var arr = ['cats', 'giants', 'daughters', 'ice'];
var min = Math.min(...arr.map(o => o.length));
console.log(min);
```

Comment: But you don't find the shortest string. You find the shortest string's length.. Despite OP has accepted your answer i believe the answer still remains unsolved.

Comment: The problem is in the phrasing of the question. Look at the op's code.

Answer (score 30):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
var arr = ["aaaa", "aa", "aa", "aaaaa", "a", "aaaaaaaa"];

console.log(
  arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.length <= b.length ? a : b;
  })
)
```

---

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
var arr = ["aaaa", "aa", "aa", "aaaaa", "a", "aaaaaaaa"];

console.log(
  arr.reduce((a, b) => a.length <= b.length ? a : b)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
const arr = ['small', 'big', 'yuge']

const shorter = (left, right) => left.length <= right.length ? left : right

console.log(
  arr.reduce(shorter)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = ["aaaa", "aa", "aa", "aaaaa", "a", "aaaaaaaa"];

console.log(
  arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.length <= b.length ? a : b;
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var arr = ["aaaa", "aa", "aa", "aaaaa", "a", "aaaaaaaa"];

console.log(
  arr.reduce(function(r, a) {
    return Math.min(r, a.length);
  }, Infinity)
);
```

ES6

```js
var arr = ["aaaa", "aa", "aa", "aaaaa", "a", "aaaaaaaa"];

console.log(arr.reduce((r, a) => Math.min(r, a.length), Infinity));
```

Answer (score -4):

Please see this short solution below. I hope it helps:

```
var arr = ['cats', 'giants', 'daughters', 'ice'];    
arr.sort(); // ice, cats, giants, daughters
var shortest_element = arr[0]; // ice
```

Comment: Sort sorts on alphabet. Not on string length. The output there will be "cats" not "ice".