# Do the arrays have javascript methods to know the shortest element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-length

I looked in the MDM documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array to see if the arrays had some method to determine the shortest element of or longer of an array, and I did not find the solution.
Is there any way to make it as simple as possible, or should I create a function to achieve it?
Is there another place where you look for information?

> I EDIT the question:
>   My intention is to find out the longest text string in the following array:`var valores = [true, 5, false, "hola", "adios", 2]`Only text strings
>    are taken into account, not the numbers in the array

Forgive the confusion, I think there is no similar question, or I ran away, well look.
Thank you.

Comment: Write a function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864915/find-the-shortest-string-in-array

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It's the easiest way to find the element with the longest item:

```js
var valores = ["true", "false", "hola", "adios", "miercoles"];


var res = valores.reduce((prev, current) => {
  return (prev.length > current.length) ? prev : current
});

console.log(res);
```

If you only want the max length, it becomes a bit easier:

```js
var valores = ["true", "false", "hola", "adios", "miercoles"];


var res = valores.reduce((prev, current) => {
  return Math.max(prev, current.length);
}, 0);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @gemita Use my first block of code to find the longest, and then follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767357/4875631).

Comment: It works perfectly @FrankerZ, but I made an error when writing the question, because I need to remove the longest text string from this array:                                 `var valores = [true, 5, false, "hola", "adios", 2]`                                                                   
Should I edit the question?                                                                              
 Sorry for the language error

Comment: Yes, please edit the question and be as clear as possible. Explain why your answer is not a duplicate.

Comment: @gemita Also, the function that I listed should still work correctly. `.length` returns undefined on ints/strings, so it should work as expected.

Comment: Well, it does not work for me, because the result of `console.log (res)` is 2, and I need you to check only the text strings within the array, without evaluating the numbers, and without evaluating true and false. Only text strings