# what is the shortest word in this array using function and easy method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to find the shortest name in this array in javascript. like

```
var a = ['john','mahmud','nasimon','Jheather','jo','moon','calibration'];
```

now, what is the shortest word in this array?
and I would like to know the beginner method.
thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the shortest string in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864915/find-the-shortest-string-in-array)

Comment: [Search results for the title of the question](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+find+the+shortest+word+in+an+array+in+javascript+site%3Astackoverflow.com). Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method easy to understand , using simple for loop .
Please take a note that this method is assuming there are no two strings with same length . If there are two strings with same length , then it will print the first shortest element in the array.

```js
var arr = ['john','mahmud','nasimon','Jheather','jo','moon','calibration'];

function findShortestElem(array){

let minEle = array[0];

for(let i=1;i<array.length;i++){
    
    if(array[i].length<minEle.length){
      minEle = array[i];
    }
}

return minEle;
}

console.log(findShortestElem(arr));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wanted something like that. Now I have one last question. would you please hlep me?

Comment: Please tell me.

Comment: can please use a function?

Comment: You mean create a function which accepts array and gives back the shortest element

Comment: yes, sir. thats how i want a result. please help

Comment: Updated the code . please check

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic case for reducing an array, if you have only one shortest string in the array.

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) uses an accumulator (the first parameter) and the value from the array as second parameter and returns in this case the shorter string.

If no start value is available, the first two values of the array are taken.

```js
const
    array = ['john', 'mahmud', 'nasimon', 'Jheather', 'jo', 'moon', 'calibration'],
    shortest = array.reduce((a, b) => a.length <= b.length ? a : b);

console.log(shortest);
```

Answer (score 0):

A *beginner method* as you **ask** can be to iterate trough all the elements and check their length and add it to a variable.

Like:

```js
    let a = ['john','mahmud','nasimon','Jheather','jo','moon','calibration'];
    let shortest = false;

    a.forEach( name => {

         if(!shortest || shortest.length > name.length) shortest = name;
    })

    console.log(shortest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```js
 var a = ['john','mahmud','nasimon','Jheather','jo','moon','calibration'];
     var len=a.map(n=>n.length) //first get the names lenghts 
     var min=Math.min(...len)//use the Math class to get the minimum number 
     var result=a.find(name=>name.length==min) //find the name and match the length
      console.log(result)
```