# Using the filter method to find the shortest element in an Array Or another style

Tags: javascript

```
function findShortestElement(arr) {
  var shortestElement = [];


  for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].length > shortestElement) {
      
    }
  }

  return shortestElement;
}

var output = findShortestElement(['a', 'two', 'three']);
console.log(output); // --> 'a'
```

Got stuck here, i'm assuming I could do this without the filter method but i'm not sure how. I usually set the shortestElement to infinity then do if an if statement. Any help on how to accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864915/find-the-shortest-string-in-array

Answer (score 3):

```js
function findShortestElement(arr){
    return arr.sort((a,b)=>a.length-b.length)[0]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with [Javascript Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
function findShortestElement(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.length <= b.length ? a : b;
  })
}

var output = findShortestElement(['a', 'two', 'three']);
console.log(output); // --> 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just followed your way.

```
function findShortestElement(arr) {
      var shortestElement = arr[0];
      var shortestLength = arr[0].length
      for (var i = 1; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i].length < shortestLength) {
           shortestElement = arr[i];
           shortestLength = arr[i].length
        }
      }

  return shortestElement;
}

var output = findShortestElement(['a', 'two', 'three']);
console.log(output); // --> 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findShortestElement(arr = []) {
  let shortestElementIndex = -1, shortestElementLength = Infinity;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // if current element's length is less than shortestElementLength, update
    if(arr[i].length < shortestElementLength) {
      shortestElementIndex = i;
      shortestElementLength = arr[i].length;
    }
  }
  return arr[shortestElementIndex];
}

var output = findShortestElement(['a', 'two', 'three']);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function findShortestElement(arr) {
      if (arr.length <= 0) {
          return '';
      }
      let shortest = arr[0];
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].length < shortest.length) {
           shortest = arr[i];
        }
      }
  return shortest;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Consider adding some text to explain your answer. Just code is not enough.